# If $f(a)$ is invertible under a ring homomorphism $f$, is $a$ invertible too?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, inverse, ring-homomorphism

Suppose $f\colon R\to S$ is a ring homomorphism (and *not* rng homomorphism, wherein $f(1) = 1$ is not generally true). I can prove that if $a$ is invertible$^1$, then $f(a)$ also is, with its inverse being $f(a^{-1})$. However, I am not able to prove the converse, that is, if $f(a)$ is invertible, then $a$ also is, or give a counterexample.

Any help?

I've just begun studying about these things from Stillwell's *Elements of Agebra*, and though these are not the questions that are required to be answered in the text, these just pop up in my head, and I think that MathSE is the best place to ask them.

---

$^1$By inverses here, I mean multiplicative inverses.

Comment: Not my area of expertise, but looks like a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/820849/42969 to me.

Comment: @MartinR Ah, I didn't come across it. But since Mark below has answered (and I want to accept that), should I still delete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the canonical projection $\pi:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$. The image is a field, and so the element $\pi(2)=2+5\mathbb{Z}$ is invertible. However, $2$ is obviously not invertible in $\mathbb{Z}$.